# How to use third-party jar file in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-library

I know this question asked before but any answer helped me.

I want to use SVG but Android can't see SVG jar. I added build path. And I attach library resuorce as libs folder. And also added  tag in Android Manifest. But it didn't work.

Regards

Here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.svgexample2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.svgexample2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>          
        </activity>
         <uses-library android:name="svg-android" android:required="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Main Activity :

```
package com.example.svgexample2;

import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        RelativeLayout mainLayout;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ImageView myImg;
        SVG svgFile;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            myImg = new ImageView(this);

            myImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            SVG svgFile = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
            myImg.setImageDrawable(svgFile.createPictureDrawable());

            mainLayout.addView(myImg);
            setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my additional svgandroid.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<permissions>
<libraryname="svg-android" file="/home/breed/dev/Android/androidWorkspace/SvgExample2/libs/"/>
</permissions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no need that you place a `uses-library` in your Manifest. The `svgandroid.xml` should be useless, too. Just place the `.jar` files in the `libs` folder from your Android Eclipse Project.

Comment: Greeny, I tried that. I get "This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be 
 found." error.

Comment: Javadoc is not relevant here. When you try to build or start the application, which error message do you see?

Comment: @BreedHansen What is not working? Your javadoc(mouse hover popups) is showing "This element neither......" or your image is not showing?

Comment: @IronBlossom. you are right. but i get nul pointer exception. And i can see svg jar under libs folder. I dont know, where I made mistake.

Comment: I think your svgFile is not properly initialized. Try Project>Clean and then Run again.

Comment: Remove `<uses-library android:name="svg-android" android:required="true" />` then Run again

Comment: Thanks, IronBlossom. It's worked. I removed <uses-library android:name="svg-android" android:required="true" />, and clean. And Run. It's worked.